# Having trouble to identify web element when class attribute contains ng-hide on a single page application

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to validate while class attribute contains **"ng-hide"**, the Section will not display on the web app. And I am trying to verify

`"Element=//*[@id='index-13'][@class='col-3 uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-hide']"` does not exist with the code below:

```
WebElement We = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(Element)));

Assert.assertFalse(We.isDisplayed(), strScenarioName + ":# WebElement '" + Element + "' is not Exist Validation. Element(s) is displayed: " + We.isDisplayed());
```

Here is the DOM :

```
 <li id="index-13" class="col-3 uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-hide" ng-class="[{active: active, disabled: disabled}, classes]" ng-click="claims.chargelineDetailCall('Section Indicator')" ng-show="claims.isApprovedClaim()" heading="Benefit Indicators" index="13">
 <a class="nav-link ng-binding" uib-tab-heading-transclude="" ng-click="select($event)" href="">Section Indicator</a>
```

I am getting below error:

```
   org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //*[@id='index-13'[@class='col-3 uib-tab nav-item ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-hide']
  Build info: version: '2.53.1',
```

Note: I tried with `By.id`, `By.cssSelector`, `By.name` and so on but nothing is working. Please advise me how to over come the situation

Comment: can you add relevant html code?

Comment: ...and properly format the code and HTML in your question so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a whole lot of classes in your xpath, you could've use the `@contains()` method to see if the `<li>` is actually visible.

I think your xpath should look like this -

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class,'ng-hide') and @contains(@id,13)")))

//include your assert statement here.
```

This code is in Python, however, you can use the XPATH locator and use it in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the element can be found using "//li[@id='index-13']"

```
By elementBy = By.xpath("//li[@id='index-13']");
        If(driver.findElement(elementBy).getAttributes("class").contains("ng-hide")){
             Assert.assertTrue(true,waitForInvisibilityOfWebElement(driver, elementBy ));     
    }

 public static boolean waitForInvisibilityOfWebElement(WebDriver driver, By locator){
                boolean result = false;
                System.out.println("Fluently waiting for invisibility of element with locator: " +locator.toString());
                try {
                    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)  
                            .withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)                  
                            .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)           
                            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)                     
                            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);                    
                    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator));
                    result = true;  
                } catch(TimeoutException e) {
                    System.out.println("TimeoutException occurred while waiting for invisibility of element " +locator.toString()+ " : " +e.getMessage());
                    result = false;
                }
            return result;
    }
```